# Groovy FindAll Roughly/Like

Tags: groovy, findall

I am trying to do something in Groovy similar to SQL's `WHERE NAME LIKE %JOHN%`

Here is what I have:

```
response.entries = json.entries.findAll { it.name.toUpperCase() =~ /lookupQuery.toString().toUpperCase()/  }
```

This is working if I use ==, but something is wrong with my code doing a LIKE search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lookupQuery` isn't inserted in the regular expression.
In this case however, you don't really need to use regular expressions:

```
json.entries.findAll { it.name.toUpperCase().contains(lookupQuery.toString().toUpperCase()) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
json.entries.findAll { it.name.toUpperCase() ==~ /.*${lookupQuery.toUpperCase()}.*/ }
```